# Invalid_message not displaying in proper format in reset password

Tags: symfony, twig

My reset form looks like

```
 $builder
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options' => [
                    'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotBlank([
                            'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                        ]),
                        new Length([
                            'min' => 6,
                            'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                            // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                            'max' => 4096,
                        ]),
                    ],
                    'label' => 'New password',
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                    'label' => 'Repeat Password',
                ],
                'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                // Instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
        ;
```

I was performing testing to check if I enter wrong password than how the web page looks like. The problem is the invalid message shows after new password input box (like below). I want the "The password fields must match" to be on top of New Password

```
Reset your password
New password
The password fields must match.
|INPUTBOX|
Repeat Password|INPUTBOX|
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your twig page you should display the form like that:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_label(form.password.first) }}
{{ form_errors(form.password.first) }}
{{ form_widget(form.password.first) }}
//other fields
{{ form_end(form) }}
```